# Doctrine transactions - count number of pending requests

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, transactions, symfony-3.2

Is there a way to **find out the number of pending requests in a transaction** before launching the commit action ?

I want to launch my commit only if I get a sufficient number of queries (that I can not count one by one before in my particular case...)

Comment: Do you need to only calculate the number of SQL queries, or could the list of affected entities suit you ? If you are in the latter case, taking a look at [the unit of work](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html) might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I find this in the UOF

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#3134

so this method will do the job

```
count($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions())
```